# How to rehighlight next line (textblock) after stadart highlightblock is done?

Tags: python, pyqt, highlight

I am writing cod editor with modal commands (modifiers that would stop work when you cancel it). I know how many lines would be highlighted
by **my_QsyntaxHighlighter**.

But I need to rehighlight lines after, because it might receive new modal command from edited lines.

I tried to call **my_rehighlighter** from the last **highlightblock**, but it end colourizing after return only. Enclosure **highlightBlock** in **highlightBlock**. And rehighlighted banch of lines will have another last block to highlight. Another reghilight function will be started but it will end immediately by condition. In the moment of this return program crashing and debugger failing. I see almost colorized text (except last line to highlight and last line to reghilight).
**From where should I call reghilightNextBlocks to not make it Enclosure?** I don't see any highlight signals at least. Maybe I should use highlight without connecting it to the my_qplaintext? What is better, what is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a beautiful solution, so i made a workaround with eventFilter. I already overrided it anyway.

```
def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and widget is self):
            key = event.key()
            if something1:
                 do something1 manually, without universal return QWidget.eventFilter(self, widget, event)
                 rehighlightNextBlocks()
                 return True
            elif something1:
                 do something1
                 rehighlightNextBlocks()
                 return True
        return QWidget.eventFilter(self, widget, event)
```